# How to overlap view in swift using storyboryboard

Tags: swift, storyboard

I am using xcode-14.2. I need to overlay like below image. Here is my image

[image]

I have tried in storyboard. But overlap the textfield. Here is the image like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The desired interface, of itself, is not difficult to achieve; our app uses it:

[image]

We do not, however, overlap two views; it just *looks* as if we do. The illusion is achieved by drawing.

So my first recommendation is that you use drawing, not true overlapping, to achieve the desired interface. If you insist upon using overlapping, then keep in mind that the order in the document outline at the left is back to front order. If you want the "select source account" to overlap in front of "available balance", you would need to bring the former to the front.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for reply. I have tried. I am doing some wrong. I tried like@IBOutlet weak var viewRed: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewBlue: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.viewRed.bringSubviewToFront(viewBlue)
    }

Comment: I've said everything I can given the limited information you've provided. My suggestion, by the way, was about a thing you would do in the storyboard, not in code. We don't use storyboards so we are able to take a much more deterministic approach to our interface.